# Is it possible to customise the source sets used by the Gradle license plugin?

Tags: gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'license'

license {
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude '**'
        }
        test {
            exclude '**'
        }
    }
}
    mapping {
    javascript='JAVADOC_STYLE'
    xml='XML_STYLE'
    xsl='XML_STYLE'
    html='XML_STYLE'
    Rptdesign='XML_STYLE'
  }
}
```

I have read that by default license is added to all sourceSets created by Java Plugin.to customise sourceSets - when i add sourceSets license is not adding to .java files,when i remove sourceSets block license is updating  all .java,.groovy files in src/main/ test & java directiries but i have to add license for specfic files like .xml,.xsl at root directory and some specific java files like which starts with s*.java, can any one helpme.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and  I found a solution here : https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/9

You can add the following to your build.gradle and then the license plugin skips the excluded files.

```
import nl.javadude.gradle.plugins.license.License
tasks.withType(License).each { licenseTask ->
    licenseTask.exclude '/*.json'
    licenseTask.exclude '/*.properties'
}
```

( and remove `license { sourceSets { ... } }`)